Azure Container App revision, resource issue
I have ACA environment with 12 vCPU capacity with I have 3 ACA in that environment each allocated with 4 vCPU. The configuration works fine in single revision mode But when I switch to multiple revision mode and add more, it throws an error workload profile is full.
Does new revisions require other 4 vCPU's ? Don't they share the same resources which are already allocated to ACA's? All revision will require their own resources or all will share same ?
For example, In multiple revision mode each revision will require 4 vCPU or all will be shared 4 vCPU.

In multiple revision mode, each revision can have its own resources allocated, including CPU and memory. Therefore, adding more revisions will require additional resources beyond what is already allocated to the existing ACA instances. It's possible that the total resources required by all revisions exceed the capacity of the workload profile, resulting in the "workload profile is full" error. To resolve this issue, you may need to increase the resources allocated to the workload profile or reduce the number of revisions.

If you have an environment with a 12 vCPU capacity and 3 ACA each allocated with 4 vCPUs in single revision mode, that sums up to the total vCPU capacity of your environment. When you try to run multiple revisions, each additional revision will require its own share of CPU and memory resources. They do not share the resources that have already been allocated to existing ACAs.
In your scenario, if you switch to multiple revision mode, you'll have more than one revision of an ACA running at the same time, which means you would exceed the available resources if each revision requires the same amount of CPU as you've configured for a single revision.
Here’s how it works:

Single Revision Mode: Your single revision of each ACA uses up the 4 vCPUs allocated. Since you have 3 ACAs, that's 12 vCPUs in total, which matches the capacity of your ACA environment.

Multiple Revision Mode: Each active revision requires its own allocation of resources. So, if you have one ACA and enable a second revision for it (and each revision is configured to use 4 vCPUs), you would need an additional 4 vCPUs available in your environment. This would go beyond your current capacity of 12 vCPUs.


Therefore, in multiple revision mode, if each revision is configured to require 4 vCPUs, you would need additional capacity in your ACA environment to support more than the original three revisions.
To handle multiple revisions without exceeding your environment's capacity, you can

Scale Down Each Revision*: Allocate fewer vCPUs to each revision so that the combined total does not exceed your environment's capacity.
Increase Environment Capacity*: Add more vCPUs to your ACA environment to support additional revisions.
Limit Number of Active Revisions*: Configure your deployment to limit the number of active revisions that can run simultaneously.

References:

Update and deploy changes in Azure Container Apps - Work with multiple revisions
Update and deploy changes in Azure Container Apps - Revision modes
Workload profiles in Azure Container Apps - Resource consumption

